# использование react+flux/redux на apache

Tags: node.js, apache, flux, redux

Помогите немного по полкам разложить ситуацию...

Есть проект - там все стандартно "клиент html + js" и "серверная часть php", размещено все на стандартном apache web server под centos 6.4. Хочу переписать кусок проекта на react flux/redux но как быть с сервером - во всех туториалах подымается express от node.js и там прекрасно все работает. Я попробовал написать простейшее приложение на redux - запускается только на express что в общем понятно сервер должен уметь рендерить страницы. Но в итоге мы имеем ситуацию при которой под react flux/redux нужно поднимать уникальную инфраструктуру и делать проект полностью под ней. То есть мой проект перевести на react постепенно не получится, или все - таки есть варианты?

Comment: Эм, что? Redux/Flux это архитектура клиентской части, при чём тут сервер вообще?

Comment: Ну кто знаком с react/flux понимают "при чем тут сервер вообще" повторюсь что flux/redux это рендеринг клиентской части на сервере, поэтому сервер это рендеринг должен поддерживать. Кое что я нарыл типа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server или http://garrows.com/blog/running-node-js-and-apache-together-using-mod_proxy/  и на всякий случай повторю вопрос - как постепенно имея клиентскую часть js + html перевести ее на redux. в общем то я уже придумал кое-что типа:

Comment: Я знаком с [`re-frame`](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame), использующим ту же идею, что и Flux. Flux тут ни при чём. **Серверный рендеринг** React это совершенно другая тема (и для применения Flux необязательная) и да, обычно это решают, рендеря тот же код чуть "побритой" версией React, работающей на сервере; поскольку React на JS, там нужен исполнитель на JS, например NodeJS. Но я, кажется, уже начал отвечать на вопрос?..

Comment: На всякий случай уточню вопрос - как постепенно имея клиентскую часть js + html перевести ее на redux. В общем то я уже придумал кое-что типа: - перевести сервер на REST -поднять таки express Node.js на серверной машине, повесить его на 80 порт ну и соответственно запросы к серверу на клиенте осуществлять как к REST сервису предварительно повесив Apache на какой нибудь порт 8080.  Не знаю правильно ли я думаю, хочу услышать мысли того кто делал что-то похожее.

Comment: А для чего всё это? Какова конечная цель переезда на Flux/Redux? Чтобы упростить разработку клиентского приложения? Так для этого серверная часть вообще необязательна, это может быть чистейшее клиентское приложение без поддержки со стороны сервера.

Comment: ...приложение на React вполне может отрендерить себя самостоятельно на клиенте. Я к этому клоню. Или вас что-то не устраивает в таком подходе?

Comment: Я человек в этом деле новый, неделю назад стал смотреть туториалы, обучающие видео ну например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYvdeFfZ_NE или https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/redux-course-ru/content/index.html в которых ребята со старта поднимают express не объясняя зачем это надо и как потом это хозяйство деплоить в продакшн.  Я тоже начиная смотреть в сторону Redux думал ну это же фронтэнд, причем тут сервер, написал кусок в веб шторме, переписал структуру папок проекта на сервер, подкрутил апач если надо  и все должно рботать. Вник в оф доки, вы правы http://redux.js.org/index.html, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Фактически React + Flux, это архитектура клиентского приложения. Что именно вы используете на серверной стороне не имеет значения. Особенно в контексте REST архитектуры. Вы вполне можете реализовать REST API к вашему существующему приложению на PHP, а клиентскую часть реализовывать на Flux + React.

Однако, есть одно но. В связке с React + Flux *часто* используют node.js + express (хотя это вовсе не обязательно). Тому есть несколько причин:

- Использование одного и того же языка программирования на сервере и клиенте позволяет повторно использовать один и тот же программный код.
- Использование одного языка программирования позволяет уволить весь штат серверных программистов и заменить их JavaScript разработчиками широкого профиля. (На практике, такое решение может оказаться сомнительным.)
- Типичной проблемой SPA приложений является SEO (отложим дискуссии о возможностях современных поисковых роботов). Суть проблемы сводится к тому, что при запросе какой-то страницы поисковой робот получает не готовый HTML код целевой страницы, а "болванку", которая наполняется реальной разметкой и данными уже не клиенте. В ряде случаев, используются специальные ухищрения, чтобы при обращении рендерить страницу полностью на сервере, а на клиенте уже инициализировать SPA. Все это требует одних и тех же фреймворков на клиенте и сервере.

Мне кажется, что в вашем случае разработчики руководств просто умолчали о возможности использования на сервере чего-то, отличного от node.js. Скорее всего, это было сделано специально, дабы оградить новичков от излишней сложности.